# When can Request object be null in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, httprequest

I found a Null Reference Exception in logs, related to a controller method. Is there any scenario that Request object can be null?

This is the error I am getting.
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
The line which getting error is the following

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]
```

Comment: Share more details and the `code snippet` where you are getting the exception.

Comment: How have you set the `Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` within your application?

Comment: What value did you set on `FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes`?The cookie won't exist in the AuthenticateRequest unless it's verified. Make sure the cookie isn't expiring early

Comment: What are you getting here `var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);`?

Comment: There is no FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes setup in the application. Using the above cookie value, creating a custom class instance